# How to check if a workload is installed on client's visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, blazor-webassembly

I'm working on a class library targeting Blazor wasm, and to work properly the client will need the wasm-tools workload installed on their instance of visual studio.

Is there any way to check if they have it installed, and produce an error message of some sort if it isn't the case ?

Thank you.

Comment: May I know whether your issue have been solved or not? if not, please share it in here, we can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 5):

As I know, wasm-tools workload is installed by using a dotnet command line(`dotnet workload install wasm-tools`) in an administrative command shell. See this doc: ***[.NET WebAssembly build tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tooling?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=windows#net-webassembly-build-tools)***.

So if you used above command line, you might see following message, for example:

> Successfully installed workload(s) wasm-tools.

[image]

If you see this message then you can confirm that the workload was successfully installed.

**But for your question**, perhaps you can consider using dotnet command(***[dotnet workload list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-workload-list)***) like

`dotnet workload list`

to check if it lists in the Installed Workload list, for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio installer supports exporting and importing installation configurations as .vsconfig files. Starting with VS2019 a .vsconfig file can be added to the solution folder as a peer of the .sln file and Visual Studio will use the .vsconfig to check for missing installer items.

See "[Import or export installation configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2022)", especially the section "[Automatically install missing components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/import-export-installation-configurations?view=vs-2022#automatically-install-missing-components)".

The .vsconfig stores IDs for components and workloads. The IDs are documented in "[Visual Studio workload and component IDs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-and-component-ids?source=recommendations&view=vs-2022)".

Visual Studio workloads and .Net SDK workloads are different things but there are workload IDs for the installer that appear to map to the .Net SDK workloads.

e.g. The installer IDs `wasm.tools` and `wasm.tools.net6` appear to map to the SDK workloads `wasm-tools` and `wasm-tools-net6`, respectively. But you will need to test to confirm.

The .vsconfig file that is placed next to the .sln file doesn't need to be complete. You can edit the file to strip out all but the IDs of specific interest. Or you can create the most minimal install of Visual Studio that is still capable of building your solution and export its configuration.

This approach is leveraging a feature of the Windows version of the Visual Studio IDE and it's very helpful -- if you are using Visual Studio. If you are using other tools or need a build time error, see @Tianyu's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74740486/4208174) which uses `dotnet workload list`. (Running the `dotnet workload list` command and checking the output could be performed by an MSBuild target.)